# Pytorch training model with multiple Datasets on multi GPUS

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, transformer-model, dataloader, multi-gpu

I have multiple data generators(say 16), each of them are time related, such that I can only generate the data one by one (batch size of each generator are fixed as one). And I have 8 gpus, how can I train the model with all the data simutaneously, something like data generator NO.1 and NO.2 goes to the gpu NO1, data generator NO.3 and NO.4 goes to the gpu NO2 and etc..., something like below in a multiprocess way:

```
# dataloaderpairs = {'device1':(dataloader1, dataloader2), 'device2':(dataloader3, dataloader4).......]}
for gpu_x in my_gpus: 
    for (input1,target1), (input1,target1) in my zip(*dataloaderpairs[gpu_x]):
         model = model.to(gpu_x)
         x  = torch.cat([input1, input2],axis=0).to(gpu_x)
         target = torch.cat([target1, target2],axis=0).to(gpu_x)
         out = model(x)
         losses[gpu_x]+= criterion(out, target)
mloss = merge_the_loss(losses)
mloss.backward()
```

Comment: Have you tried DistributedDataParallel? That's usually the best way to go. Check this tutorial - https://yangkky.github.io/2019/07/08/distributed-pytorch-tutorial.html You need to do quite a bit more than just assign tensors to different GPUs.

Comment: I have checked out lots of turial, but I still can't figure out how to deal with my type of data structure, like most of these lib sare well-sealed with certain structure of data

Comment: I would still recommend this tutorial because I also struggled with DDP but this really helped me understand DDP well enough to implement it for my custom use-case. It is quite general and you can extend it for any kind of data. The basic thing is that you need to have a function which has one of its arguments as the GPU id and then the `multiprocessing` module is able to parallelize it over multiple GPUs.